# CMake How to make project export header files before dependent project build

Tags: cmake

There are 2 projects in `proj1/` and `proj2/`. `proj1` is a library, and `proj2` is an executable which uses `proj1`.

The dir tree is like:

```
repo/
  include/
  proj1/
    hello.h
    hello.cpp
  proj2/
    testApp.cpp // it #include hello.h
```

CMake will make `proj1` then `proj2`. I want CMake to copy `hello.h` to `include/` when it builds `proj1`, if the file is not updated, so that `proj2` build will succeed.

Currently I only know to use `install()`:

```
install(FILES hello.h DESTINATION $ENV{REPO_ROOT_DIR}/include)
```

However, this only export file when `make install`. It doesn't happen in the normal sequence of build tasks.

Comment: Have you tried [target_include_directories](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/target_include_directories.html) on the target of `proj2`? It seems that there's a confusion between configuration/building and the install step.

Comment: @compor How do I use target_include_directories to achieve this goal? I know target_include_directories but I understand it is to add include dirs for target, like proj2, not to copy files

Comment: you don't need to copy header files to use them in a project; just point the compiler to the right directory.

Answer (score 4):

Never write to the source tree during the build.

CMake is supposed to be used for out-of-source builds, so I should be able to build even if the source is located on a read-only filesystem.

As was pointed out [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48763885/cmake-how-to-make-project-export-header-files-before-dependent-project-build#comment84535273_48763885), in the simple case where the header is already present and not changed by the build of `proj1`, you can just `target_include_directories` its folder into `proj2` and be done.

If that is, for whatever reason, not applicable and you really need to copy the file to a different place, you should copy it to a folder under the [`PROJECT_BINARY_DIR`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.10/variable/PROJECT_BINARY_DIR.html) and then `target_include_directories` to that. Depending on what information you need to have available for copying the file, you can either perform the copying at CMake configure time (using eg.
 [`configure_file`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.10/command/configure_file.html)) or at build time, using [`add_custom_command`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.10/command/add_custom_command.html). In the latter case you need to make sure that you model your dependencies accordingly, so that `proj2` is not allowed to build before the file has been copied.

Comment: Does it mean in CMake, there is no need to export public header files to a top-level include/ like before? How do I use target_include_directories here? Should I say: target_include_directories(proj2 PUBLIC ../proj1) ?

Comment: @Sheen why don't you try it? what's the worst thing that can happen? Also, what do you mean "like before"?

Comment: @Sheen You should always prefer passing absolute paths to CMake commands. So it should be something like `target_include_directories(proj2 PUBLIC ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/proj1)`. It is okay to add include directories outside your immediate directory, but you should refrain from adding non-system include directories outside of the source tree (like, doing a `${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/../foo` to go above the root of your project source).

Comment: @ComicSansMS It works now. But what if my proj2 needs to #include 20 projects' header files? Do I add 20 target_include_directories() ? In my current practise, e.g. makefile, no CMake, all the projects' public header files are copied to a top include/ dir.

Comment: @Sheen That's how it's supposed to work, yes. Keep in mind that CMake has to support all kinds of different compiler toolchains, each coming with their different constraints. As a result, specific tasks are often more cumbersome than with your favorite toolchain, but that's the price you pay for a portable build.

Comment: @ComicSansMS I think I understand what you mean, but it is still not convincing to me. Major toolchains all support pre-build / post-build events. It is not harmful to provide the option.

Comment: @Sheen CMake supports pre- and post-build events through `add_custom_command`. That doesn't take care of setting any include paths for compilation though.

Comment: @ComicSansMS I just spotted this command actually. It is what I am looking for. Include path can be set at beginning at top level.